# HTML form opens PHP script instead of running it

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am using WAMP with MySQL and PHP to run a local server. The WAMP server is online and I use a simple HTML script to run PHP file that connects to a database and inserts data in a table that I have created on WAMP server.

The problem is that instead of running (executing) my script, the browser opens it in text mode. As in I can see the script.

Now there have been similar questions on this forum and others and people have solved the problem. However what makes my problem unique is that I am able to run a `test.php`. I am able to display text with it as well as open `info.php` so PHP is running on my server, however when I use the HTML form it refuses to run and only opens the script.

I am using Chrome browser and I have also checked it in Firefox with the same result.

I have one HTML file that is a form linked to my PHP files which handles connection and insertion of values in the table on the WAMP server. The name of the database is test.

#### form.html

```
<form action= "create_product.php" method= "get">
    <center>
       <table>
            <td><label><b><font size="5"> Name</label></td>
            <td><font size="5"><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><label><b><font size="5"> Description</label></td>
            <td><font size="5"><input type="text" Description="description" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <center><td></td></center>
            <center><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
            </tr>
            
       </table>
    </center>
```

#### insert_product.php

```
<?php
$con= mysql_connect("localhost", "admin","");
$db = mysql_select_db("test");

$name = $_GET["name"];
$description = $_GET["description"];

$query = "Insert into products('name','description')values('".$name."','".$description."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: sounds like your server is miss-configured or that php is not even installed (or not enabled?)

Comment: How do you launch a script? As this `/some/path/script_name.php` or `www.mysite.com/script_name.php`?

Comment: <form action= "create_product.php" method= "get"> - Yet you are showing us code from insert_product. Are these actually the same file?

Comment: also, you have a typo :     mysql)connect and you should have a lowercase s in mysql_select_db

Comment: Try [Varal WAMP](http://www.VaralWAMP.com/). It is very user friendly and less buggy.

Comment: @martin server does execute php files when i use the browser...the problem starts wheni use a script

Comment: @liding i open it using localhost/foldername/filename.php....this works....through the html form is the problem

Comment: @PaulBailey that is a type the file is indeed create_product.php...my apologies .....i will chek the typ and get back....thanks guys appreciate it

Comment: guys i am newbiew at php actually a few levels below that.....but could my problem be solved by making changes to httpd.conf

Comment: Take a look at the access and error logs Apache. Maybe you will stumble on something interesting.

Comment: @liding and how do i do that.....sorry i am really new to this

Comment: By default, all log files are in `C:\wamp\logs`.

Comment: Hi @alee, how did you resolve this problem? Please share

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was surfing all known technical forums. I finally figured out what was the problem - nothing to do with PHP or Apache setup. Nothing wrong with the code (at least on mine). Here's what was NOT working:
I double-clicked to open the file from Finder (or explorer if you are a Windows user), and the URL in browser is

> "/file/xxxxx/foo.html"

.  This would open

> /file/xxxx/bar.php"

, which doesn't work!

However, if I typed into the URL in browser

> "localhost/~xxx/foo.html"

, it runs nicely when

> "bar.php"

is called.

Perhaps this is what you can try.

> "file:///XXXX/foo.php"

doesn't work, but

> "localhost/XXX/foo.php"

does.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you open it  localhost/yourfile.php not like C:\wamp\yourfile.php

Start all services

or try xampp [download](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

tried wamp and xampp , in my opinion xampp is better

Comment: XAMPP is very clunky though, it's bigger than WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

This is edit- If u have tested that PHP is working on your local server,then the most probable cause for text display could be missing php end tag(?>)

Also please note that if u have saved your file as anything other than .php,it will not be parsed. Files containing PHP code but saved as HTML or doc file renders the php codes within it useless.

<<--EDIT ENDS-->>

u gave `action= "create_product.php"` in form although u specified the php file as `insert_product.php`

Also as a good practice,always provide database connection variable in mysql_select_db

use `$db = mysql_select_db("test",$con);`

instead of `$db = mysql_select_db("test");`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change the fact that the author sees the text of the script, even if it's another script.

Comment: @mayur....i have php end tag and the file is saved as php....i have enabled extension in window 7 so there is no chance that the file might actually be filename.php.txt.......

i noted the good practise and the create and insert thing is a mistake when i was writing the question that actual file names and form action tally.

Comment: guys if it is any help.....when i submit the form entry the browser displays the following url "file:///C:/wamp/www/transformers/create_product.php?name=sunsilk"

chrome shows my code as text on this web address and firefox does not display anything....as in blank page

Comment: i have never heard of a description attribute for input tag.Hoping that its a actual mistake and not a typo..as that basically is the reason url doesn't include the second text field.